# LightCouch ignores Log4j log-level

Tags: java, couchdb, log4j2

I'm using SLF4J/Log4j2 for logging in a web application running on Tomcat 8.5. While the log level works for the rest of the application LightCouch 0.2.0 keeps ignoring it. I noticed the log format also differs from the definition in my log4j2.xml.

#### catalina.out

```
10-Aug-2018 21:13:35.591 INFORMATION [http-nio-8080-exec-134] org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.process > GET /somedb/some-doc-id
10-Aug-2018 21:13:35.603 INFORMATION [http-nio-8080-exec-134] org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient.process < Status: 200
21:13:35.675 [http-nio-8080-exec-134] INFO  my.package.MyClass - Some expected log statement ...
```

#### log4j2.xml

```xml
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="my.package" level="info"/>
        <Root level="warn">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

#### Gradle dependencies

```
compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-api', version: '1.7.21'
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-slf4j-impl', version: '2.11.0'
compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.bundles', name: 'jaxrs-ri', version: '2.27'
compile group: 'nl.martijndwars', name: 'web-push', version: '3.1.1'
compile group: 'org.bouncycastle', name: 'bcprov-jdk15on', version: '1.60'
compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz', version: '2.3.0'
compile group: 'org.quartz-scheduler', name: 'quartz-jobs', version: '2.3.0'
compile group: 'javax.transaction', name: 'jta', version: '1.1'
compile group: 'org.lightcouch', name: 'lightcouch', version: '0.2.0'
```

Comment: "I noticed the log format also differs from the definition in my log4j2.xml" - since you do see logs that match the expected format this means any logs not matching your format are not generated by log4j2. A quick look at the [user guide](http://www.lightcouch.org/lightcouch-guide.html#logging) seems to indicate that it is using log4j1. Try using [log4j bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-1.2-api/index.html)

Comment: @D.B. Thanks for the hint with the log4j bridge. That made it work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not aware that Log4j2 does not handle Log4j logging out of the box. A logging bridge has to be used for that. After adding [log4j-jcl](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/log4j-jcl/index.html) the LightCouch logging finally "behaves".

#### Gradle dependency

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-jcl', version: '2.11.1'
```